# Change ActionBar title color and background using appCompat v7:22.1.1

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I have read the other stack overflow answers to this question but for some reason they do not work.

I want to change the titleColor and action bar background using this version of appcompat:

```
appcompat-v7:22.1.1
```

and these styles:

```
<style name="Theme.MyAppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
<item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.mystyle</item>              

<item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_mystyle</item>               
    <item name="textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/MyActionMenuTextAppearance.Large</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu">@style/MyActionMenuTextAppearance.Small</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/iroko_pink</item>
</style>


<style name="ActionBar.Solid.mystyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="background">@drawable/myBackground</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.SubTitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title" >
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/green</item>
</style>
```

What I am seeing is that on Gingerbread the above solution works, but on Jellybean, Kit Kat and Lollipop the action bar remains unaffected.

How should this be done so that it will work on all versions from Gingerbread on up?

Comment: are you using the toolbar as actionbar?

Comment: No. Not using the toolbar, just action bar